# How do I designate file paths in Java

Tags: java, file, path

A game that I am writing in java will require some files to be written locally for anyone that downloads the game, this is for high scores, images, achievements, etc...

Current code:

```
File file = new File("C:\\Directory\\File.txt");
```

But what I need (since I'm not going to be the only one using this) is to find the directory in which the user will download the game and operate the game, thus I can write the necessary files (on launch) to their local directory (in order to access and write to).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
File file = new File("C:\\Directory\\File.txt");
```

If you do:

```
File file = new File("File.txt");
```

You won't need to know what the path is. This will create the file in the same directory as the app.

Comment: Yes that worked... Thank you for the help... I guess I just overcomplicated things haha